# ansible loop over list with multiple items

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a definition of an array in an ansible playbook, which looks like:

```
x_php_versions:
  - php71
  - php72
  - php73
```

And I would like to make a loop for all of them, so my task looks like this:

```
- name: Install PHP packages
  yum: 
    name: '{{ item }}'
    state: 'present'
  loop:
    - '{{ x_php_versions }}'
    - '{{ x_php_versions }}-bcmath'
    - '{{ x_php_versions }}-bz2'
```

This should install php71 php71-bcmath php71-bz2 php72 php72-bcmath ... and so on. But this kind of loop does not work. Am I made a typo or my loop is completly wrong for this scenario? If I try the loop without '' then it also gave me an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the filter `product` to combine all possibilities

```
- name: Install PHP packages
  yum: 
    name: '{{ item.0 }}{{ item.1 }}'
    state: 'present'
  loop: "{{ x_php_versions | product(['', '-bcmath', '-bz2']) | list }}"
```

Comment: Should be good, but I get this error: Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: <itertools.product object at 0x7f31cb5ced38>. I get his when I use item0 or item.0

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add a `| list` filter